# sql duplicates, while one value appers once in column 1, and once in column 2

Tags: sqlite

Im trying to check how many times two teams have played against each other, while each appearing once at home and once away.

In the next table, we can see that Team 1 played against Team 2 three times, twice away and once at home, and Team 3 played against Team 4 twice, once away and once at home.

how can I do it using **sqlite**?

| id_home | id_away | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2/12 |
| 2 | 1 | 3/12 |
| 3 | 4 | 4/12 |
| 4 | 3 | 5/12 |
| 2 | 1 | 6/12 |

Answer (score 0):

You can group by sorted pairings of the `id_home` and `id_away` teams:

```
with matches as (select distinct t1.id_home h, (select t2.id_away from teams t2 where t2.id_home = t1.id_home) a from teams t1), m1 as (select case when h < a then h else a end a1, case when a < h then h else a end a2 from matches)
select m1.a1 team1, m1.a2 team2, (select sum(m1.a1 = t3.id_home) from teams t3) home, (select sum(m1.a1 = t3.id_away) from teams t3) away from m1 group by m1.a1, m1.a2;
```

Output:

```
team1 | team2 | home | away
1       2       1      2
3       4       1      1
```